# What are the German Novels for Beginners?

Tags: vocabulary, slang

After completing A2, I wish to go ahead and read interesting novels from different genres to learn new words and getting to know the slang.

Is there any recommended novels for beginners?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I vote to keep this question open, because firstly, novels / stories for that level need to be very specifically written to fit the vocabulary (no “regular” book will be adequate). That means, we are looking for learning material, not literature in general. And secondly, dcruise546 is asking for *different genres*, not *what is best*, so the reason “opinion-based” doesn’t really qualify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How strict you are with "novels"? For A2 this may be a little long. I would suggest some (online) magazine or newspaper about tasks you are interested in.

If you want stories you can look for the tales of "Brüder Grimm" (i.e. Rotkäppchen/Little Red Riding Hood; Schneewittchen/Snow White) or "Hans Christian Andersen" (Die kleine Meerjungfrau/The Little Meermaid; Das hässliche Entlein/The Ugly Duckling), maybe in a modern wording. (The originals are available over a lot of free sources online). Choose something you already know, so you can follow the story more easy. For this some Disneys stories are already a good choice.

(Edit: If you read the Brüder Grimm Tales as an adult, you can make you a fun about searching for the "hidden" adult themes. The brothers Grimm had shortened this themes of the original sources, so the tales became more fitting into the children's world. For example the love between Rapunzel and her prince results in the birth of twins, or Sleeping Beauty in the original give (asleep!) birth to some children. One of them suckle on her finger and remove a splint from the spinning wheel so she awakens...)

If you want to search for some with less children context, you can use the words "Roman in einfacher Sprache". This is for people who are not complete fit in reading because of all reasons, for example late learners, text blindness or foreign language.

Also German Wikipedia is a nice source for language learning. Only translate some words you are interested in and start the search.

I hope you enjoy :)

Comment: I am sticking with **Novel** only because I don't want to jump into children section. But wiki seems like a promising start.

Comment: Additional you can try "Graphic Novels", in difference to "normal" comics there is less word playing, I think

Comment: the Grimm fairy tales use historical / obsolete and difficult vocabulary. Them being stories that were meant to be told to children doesn’t make them a good pick for learners.

Comment: @Philipp Because of that I mentioned the "modern wording" part. I choosed them, because some of them are well known in a lot of languages and are available in a lot of free sources, so one know the main facts and can take a look on them with less effort.